# MS Access Multiple table Inner join with where clause

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have tried to inner join three tables in MS Access database but I'm getting the following error:

> "(missing operator)".

This is my query:

```
select DISTINCT
    Student.Student_Id,
    Student.Name,
    Student.Father_Name,
    Student.Dob
from (Student
    INNER JOIN Admissions
        ON Student.Student_Id = Admissions.Student_Id)
INNER JOIN Batches
    ON Admissions.Batch_Id = Batches.Batch_Id
where (Batches.Year = @p1
AND (Student.Student_Id LIKE @p2 + '%'))
```

Comment: I don't see problems with this query if it created in query builder for Access tables. Tables are MS Access or linked SQL tables? Is it pass-through query to SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You a redundant set of brackets around the `from` clause. Just remove them and you should be fine:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT
           Student.Student_Id,
           Student.Name,
           Student.Father_Name,
           Student.Dob
FROM       Student
INNER JOIN Admissions
        ON Student.Student_Id = Admissions.Student_Id
INNER JOIN Batches
        ON Admissions.Batch_Id = Batches.Batch_Id
WHERE      (Batches.Year = @p1
            AND (Student.Student_Id LIKE @p2 + '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Last line near like there must be '(single quote) both side the @p2%

means

```
AND (Student.Student_Id LIKE  '1%')
```

so make your query correct like below

```
select DISTINCT
    Student.Student_Id,
    Student.Name,
    Student.Father_Name,
    Student.Dob
from (Student
    INNER JOIN Admissions
        ON Student.Student_Id = Admissions.Student_Id)
INNER JOIN Batches
    ON Admissions.Batch_Id = Batches.Batch_Id
where (Batches.Year = @p1
AND (Student.Student_Id LIKE '' + cast(@p2 as varchar)  + '%'))
```